# Programmatic loading of modules in Angular 8+ (and Ivy-ready?)

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading, angular-ivy

My application needs to load a dynamically configured set of feature modules (each with own, additional routes) that are individually defined by a config file (loaded with XHR).
My original plan was to have a list of module strings (like "plugins/my.module#MyModule") and use `NgModuleFactoryLoader.load()` to load them while bootstrapping.

Now, when I started implementing, I saw `NgModuleFactoryLoader` is beeing deprecated in favour of the `import()` form of `LoadChildren`, which will not work in this context (I have only strings in config, no module refs).

How could I implement this in current (8+) Angular?

Comment: [Is that what you're looking for?](https://blog.angularindepth.com/asynchronous-modules-and-components-in-angular-ivy-1c1d79d45bd3)

Comment: @overthesanity Holy crap! This looks exactly like what I'm looking for. :-) You could write a full answer below, for the next researcher to find it better (and I can accept it for your deserved points :-) )

Comment: haha, danke, as you wish! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a big topic but the `NgModuleFactoryLoader` will not work anymore if you're using the Ivy compiler. Because there are no module factories anymore, only injector definitions on module classes.

There is completely new Ivy API and it will not fit in this answer by its size.

As you've asked me in comments to leave an answer thus the next researcher will find it easier. That's the link to the [Asynchronous Modules and Components in Angular Ivy](https://blog.angularindepth.com/asynchronous-modules-and-components-in-angular-ivy-1c1d79d45bd3) article. It's also available on the [indepth.dev](https://indepth.dev/asynchronous-modules-and-components-in-angular-ivy/) if the Medium link is gone.

Answer (score 0):

The new form to implement LazyLoading with import is something like this

```
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(
        mod => mod.DashboardModule
      )
  }
```

You must import the module file with the path and then select the Module implementation

Comment: How could this work programmatically, like `plugins.forEach(p => import(p).then(...))`? As far as I understood so far, the `import()` is kind of magically picked up by the angular compiler...